# Java Histogram using asterisks

Tags: java

I am trying to create a histogram class that utilizes an application to run the program.

```
 public class Histogram
{
   String name;
   int max;


   public Histogram (String name, int max)
   {
      this.name = name;
      this.max = max;
   }

   int[] count = new int[max+1];

   public void add(int numbers) 
   {
    // Handles out of bounds case
    if (numbers < 0 || numbers > max)
        return;

    count[numbers]++;
   }

   public String toString()
   {
      String result = name + "\n";
      for (int index = 0; index < count.length; index++)
      {
      result = result + count[index] + ": ";
         for (int indexStar = 0; indexStar < count[index]; indexStar++)
            result = result + "*";
         result = result + "\n";
         }
         return result;
   }
}
```

My application:

```
public class HistogramDataCollector
{
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
      Histogram h = new Histogram ("Favorite Number Survey", 11);

      h.add(1); h.add(0); h.add(9); h.add(7); h.add(7);
      h.add(3); h.add(4); h.add(6); h.add(5); h.add(2);
      h.add(2); h.add(8);

      System.out.println(h);
   }
}
```

I am struggling to figure out how to add the int numbers to get the frequency of their occurrences to formulate a histogram created with asterisks.
Thanks!

Comment: That `for` loop doesn't make sense. Why is it floating outside of a method?

Comment: Not to be snarky, but could the error be because you forgot to end the `for` loop properly? `for (int index = 0; index < max; index++ { count[numbers[index]]`??  Should this not be inside a method?

Comment: this is a rough draft of my code as I can not figure out how to count the frequency of the numbers inside of the h.add method

Comment: The definition of a histogram **is** the frequency of numbers.  As such, every element in `count` will **tell you** how many numbers occur at a particular index in your histogram.

Comment: how do I go about utilizing the count method to count the frequency of the numbers within the h.add method?

Comment: this part is where I am confused:                                                     public void add(int numbers)
   {
     count[numbers]++;
   }

Comment: Very simple.  If `count[0] = 1, count[1] = 2, count[2] = 4` as an example, this means that the number of times you have seen `0` is 1 time, `1` 2 times, and `2` 4 times in your dataset.  As such, you simply have to iterate over every element of your `count` array to retrieve the frequencies of each number.  Given your example above, after you call the various add methods, your frequency counts for each number would be: `count[0] = 1, count[1] =  1, count[2] = 2, count[3] = 1, count[4] = 1, count[5] = 1, count[6] = 1, count[7] = 2, count[8] = 1, count[9] = 1`

Comment: This code should work.  Simply get rid of that `for` loop that's outside of your method.

Comment: thank you for your help. I apologize for my confusion, but I suppose I do not understand how to instantiate the count object                                                                int count [] = new int[max];
 
   public void add(int numbers)
   {
      for (int index = 0; index < max; index++)
      {
         count[index]++;
      }
      
   }
}

Comment: That's very easy.  Remember how histograms work.  Each location in `count` is **how many** times you see that number.  As such, `numbers` is the number that you are seeing.  As such, you access that particular slot that belongs to that number, and increment the count by 1.  For example, doing `h.add(0);` would then be equivalent to `count[0]++;` which is the same as `count[0] = count[0] + 1;`.  Access slot `0`, and increment by 1.  We have seen this `1` time.  For subsequent calls to `h.add`, we would see that particular number an additional time.

Comment: Doing `int count[] = new int[max+1];` will automatically assign all elements to this array to 0.  `max` would be the highest possible number you see in your dataset.  Make sure you add `1` to account for the 0 index, which is why it's allocating for `max+1` slots.  When you create an object from this class, all of those bins will be reset to 0, and so you can start using the object right away.

Comment: thank you very much, I believe I understand this better now.

Comment: formatting my toString method to output asterisks is where I am confused as well

Comment: of course! I am new to this website, however so how do I accept it?

Comment: Once I write up my answer, you'll see my post and you'll see a checkmark icon at the top left of my answer, below the up and down vote buttons.  All you have to do is click on that checkmark when I post it :)  Thanks!  I'll write one up now.

Comment: @Kristen987 - You're welcome!  I also answered your question about placing asterisks to represent the frequency count of your histogram.  I had to modify your `toString()` method to do this.  I haven't tested this code, but it should work.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is get rid of that extraneous `for` loop code that is outside of all of your methods in your class.  This won't allow your code to compile.  However, once you remove that code, this class should work straight up.  You can also get rid of the `numbers` array as it is not being used in your class.  Just use the `count` variable, and you'll see why.

Also another note, you need to change your constructor and your variable definitions so that they look like this:

```
String name;
int max;
int[] count;

public Histogram(String name, int max) 
{
   this.name = name;
   this.max = max;
   this.count = new int[max+1];  
}
```

The reason why is because `max` is assumed to be **0** when you create an object of this class.  As such, this would declare an array of size **1**, and it would not change when you read in the `max` variable in your constructor.  As such, you need to leave this as unallocated, then allocate the array **inside the constructor**.

---

As you mentioned, you are confused with how to get the frequency of their occurrences from this histogram class.  Remember the definition of what a histogram is.  The histogram **is** the frequency of numbers that you see in your data.  The `count` array in your class will **automatically** store the frequency or how many times you see that particular number in your data set.  You use the `add()` method and the input into this method is the number you are observing to be placed in your histogram.

As an example with how a histogram works, if `count[0] = 1, count[1] = 2, count[2] = 4`, this means that the number of times you have seen `0` is 1 time, `1` 2 times, and `2` 4 times in your dataset. As such, you simply have to iterate over every element of your count array to retrieve the frequencies of each number. Given your example above in your tester class, after you call the various add methods, your frequency counts for each number would be: `count[0] = 1, count[1] =  1, count[2] = 2, count[3] = 1, count[4] = 1, count[5] = 1, count[6] = 1, count[7] = 2, count[8] = 1, count[9] = 1, count[10] = 0`.

Each location in `count` is **how many** times you see that number.  As such, for the `add()` method, `numbers` is the number that you are seeing.  As such, you access that particular slot that belongs to that number, and increment the count by 1.  For example, doing `h.add(0);` would then be equivalent to `count[0]++;` which is the same as `count[0] = count[0] + 1;`.  Access slot `0`, and increment by 1.  We have seen this `1` time.  For subsequent calls to `h.add`, we would see that particular number an additional time.

However, your add method **does not perform error checking**.  Specifically, should you specify a number that is less than 0 or larger than `max`, you will get an `OutOfBoundsException` when you try to increment the bins of your histogram.  As such, I would recommend you simply return from the method without doing anything should this happen.  In other words:

```
public void add(int numbers) {
    // Handles out of bounds case
    if (numbers < 0 || numbers > max)
        return;

    count[numbers]++;
}
```

In your class definition, doing `int count[] = new int[max+1];` will automatically assign all elements to this array to 0. `max` would be the highest possible number you see in your dataset.  Make sure you add `1` to account for the 0 index, which is why it's allocating for `max+1` slots.  We do this to ensure that we are able to log the frequency of numbers for every possible number that is seen in your dataset.  When you create an object from this class, all of those bins will be reset to 0, and so you can start using the object right away.

---

One thing I would like to note is that you said you wanted to implement this histogram by showing asterisks to represent the bin counts.  As such, you would need to modify your `toString()` method to be like this:

```
public String toString()
{
   String result = name + "\n";
   for (int index = 0; index < count.length; index++) {
       result = result + index + ": "; // New
       for (int indexStar = 0; indexStar < count[index]; indexStar++) // New
           result = result + "*"; // New
       result = result + "\n"; // New
   }
   return result;
}
```

What the above code will do is that for each bin that is in your histogram, it will show the frequency count of the number, place a colon after, a space, then place as many asterisks as there are for the frequency of that particular number.  Therefore, if you consider my first example, you should see:

```
0: *
1: **
2: ****
```

Note that I'm just showing what the frequency counts look like.  I haven't properly created an object of this class, so the name of the histogram is undefined.  However, this is what you should see for the histogram frequency counting.

---

Hope this solves your question!

Comment: thank you! it helps a lot, but there is an error for countIndex and if I have a method add(int number) would I do count[number]++? because it doesn't quite work

Comment: Yes that what you should do.  That code is the proper way to do it.  What do you mean by "doesn't quite work"?

Comment: The `countIndex` error I just corrected.  You probably used the code before I found the error.  Check out the `toString()` method now.

Comment: the only error I receive is that there is an exception out of bounds for count[number]++

Comment: The only way this can happen is if you declare your constructor improperly.  If you take a look at that example in your tester class, you see that your `max` input is 11.  If you use `h.add` with anything bigger than 11, you will get an out of bounds error.  As such, to combat this, I would recommend you modify your `add` method so that it simply returns if it's out of bounds.  I'll modify my post.

Comment: yes, but my highest add() value is 9                                 thank you so much!

Comment: i just tried the new code, but I believe there is something wrong with the numbers integer                                                                      h.add(1); h.add(7); h.add(9); h.add(7); h.add(7);
this is the problem apparently

Comment: i apologize for my many questions, i just do not understand this part

Comment: I'm getting that error too... give me a few minutes

Comment: @Kristen987 - I know why. `max` is assumed to be 0 because you **did not** initialize this when you are creating your object for this class. You need to move this into the constructor.  I have just edited my post.  This should work, and I've tried it.  Here is the modified code via pastebin to see my changes: pastebin.com/10wXE6dQ

Comment: i am still experiencing an exception out of bounds error. I have updated my code...i am very very appreciative of your help.

Comment: @Kristen987 I'm not... Did you see my pastebin link? Your constructor hasn't been updated. Please see my updated post and read the beginning

Comment: I am so very grateful for all of your help! It is working perfectly now! Thank you so much! Have a wonderful week!

Comment: @Kristen987 - You're very welcome :) This was a cool problem to solve.  Welcome to StackOverflow!